# sap.m.PlanningCalendarView Headers

Tags: sapui5

I would like to show (dates/days) in headers when implementing sap.m.

PlanningCalendarViews with Month as Interval Type like here with full months: https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/wpcontent/uploads/sites/5/2016/11/Switching_Row_Header1-1100x512.png

Codepen (https://codepen.io/Coopyrightdmin/pen/bYPORX?editors=1111):

```
<PlanningCalendar id="Calendar" viewKey="D"
        rows="{path: '/people'}"
        appointmentsVisualization="Filled"
        showEmptyIntervalHeaders="false">
        <views>
                <PlanningCalendarView
                    key="D"
                    id="CalendarView"
                    intervalType="Month"
                    intervalsS="1"
                    intervalsM="1"
                    intervalsL="1"
                    showSubIntervals="true">
                </PlanningCalendarView>
        </views>
    ...
```

Should I extend the control or is this technically possible in standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 1.50, we just need to call method setBuiltInViews("One Month")
codepen has been updated.